# is it possible to implement a pop-up/modal overlay in index.php page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

Is it possible to have a modal overlay/pop on an index.php page?

The index.php page belongs to a Joomla CMS. It is the default homepage.

However, there needs to be a redirect to another site temporarily.

I can see two solutions here:

a) have a default `index.html` which comes served first before `index.php` due to Apache's DirectoryIndex rule

b) have a modal overlay on `index.php` ...

Obviously the first one is possible.

The second one ... clearly I'm kinda clueless here, and my google-fu is not up to par here so please be kind in terms of telling to just google it ...

Is it possible to implement a modal/overlay pop in `index.php` page?

**EDIT**

Sorry, forgot to mention that the Joomla's version is 1.5.

Comment: Do you just want to redirect the page to some other website? Do you have access to the root folder of the website/joomla? If yes you could setup a 301 redirect rule. See http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/how-can-i-do-a-301-redirect

Comment: @vr3690, no, not just redirect the page as that would startle the users. I'm trying to have a user-friendly solution as the `index.php` belongs to a non-profit site ... but there is another site in which the non-profit is trying to highlight temporarily, hence this question. also ... since you talked about 301 redirect, just wondering, is option a not a good idea, if option b is not possible?

Comment: Every time I hear Joomla I get scared, specially when someone says **"Sorry, forgot to mention that the Joomla's version is 1.5"**  .... **Joomla 1.5 was released on January 22, 2008**

Comment: @PedroLobito, thanks for the colorful commentary. appreciate it. =) meanwhile, any feasible solution?

Comment: Start by updating Joomla, or completely ditch it for a **real** CMS and I may be able to help you.

Comment: @PedroLobito, not helpful as that's not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla Extensions might be helpful here. Here's one specifically for [modals](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/modals).

Beyond that, JQuery UI has a modal system called a dialog that might be helpful.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, cannot utilize this solution as the Joomla's version is 1.5. (yeah, i know, needs to be updated, but for now, this is what i'm stuck with).